# Sharepoint 2010 Date Formula for Column?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

is there a Column formula that automatically calculates the date today and converts it to PST(Pacific)? My country's time zone is +8GMT and we support people in PST time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new column to calculate the time for you, you should consider setting the timezone for your site, or for the users who are in another timezone (PST in this case).

In SharePoint, all dates are stored in [UTC](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCoordinated_Universal_Time&ei=qT3FUq-dDKXhyQHuh4HICw&usg=AFQjCNHs85L83986c2ZSZkGGbtin-02tfQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc) behind the scenes.  When SharePoint displays date values to the users, it translates the stored UTC value based a few things:

- The timezone setting of the SharePoint server *(Central Admin)*
- The timezone setting of the site collection *(Site Settings)*
- The timezone setting of the logged in user *(My Settings)*

You can have the specific users change their timezone by going to "My Settings" -> "My Regional Settings", or you can even change it for them programmatically.

[Here is an article](http://www.techgrowingpains.com/2012/05/sharepoint-time-zone-confusion-2/) that provides more details around SharePoint's timezone handling.

Comment: Awesome, I was able to change the time zone using Site Actions>Site Settings>Site Administration>Regional Settings which I found in the link you provided. Thanks!